# Parsing XML Code Metrics Report using Powershell

Tags: c#, xml, powershell, xml-parsing, powershell-3.0

I'm hoping I can get a little help over this scripting hump. I'm trying to parse this XML. Currently it's being done via C#, but I'm trying to re-write it in powershell.

```
<CodeMetricsReport Version="10.0">
  <Targets>
    <Target Name="C:\Builds\APP\APP_v1.0.0\Data.dll">
      <Modules>
        <Module Name="Data.dll" AssemblyVersion="1.0.0" FileVersion="1.0.0">
          <Metrics>
            <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="84" />
            <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="39" />
            <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="14" />
            <Metric Name="DepthOfInheritance" Value="1" />
            <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="101" />
          </Metrics>
        </Module>
      </Modules>
    </Target>
  </Targets>      
</CodeMetricsReport>
```

This is a snippet of the C# code that I'm currently using to parse the above XML.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(MetricsFileName);

XmlNodeList modules = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/CodeMetricsReport/Targets/Target/Modules/Module");
foreach (XmlNode module in modules)
{
  foreach (XmlNode nodes in module)
  {
    switch (nodes.Name)
    {                        
      case "Metrics":
      foreach (XmlNode metric in nodes)
      {
        switch (metric.Attributes["Name"].Value)
        {
          case "MaintainabilityIndex":
          Console.WriteLine("MaintainabilityIndex={0}", metric.Attributes["Value"].Value);                                        
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the PowerShell thatt I've come up with thus far, but I'm having a little trouble.

```
[xml]$xmlDoc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xmlDoc.Load($MetricsFileName)

$modules = $xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/CodeMetricsReport/Targets/Target/Modules/Module")
foreach ($module in $modules)
{
  foreach ($nodes in $module)
  {
    Switch ($nodes.Name)
    {
      "Metrics"
      {
        foreach ($metric in $nodes)
        {
          Switch ($metric.Attributes["Name"].Value)
          {
            "MaintainabilityIndex"
            {
              Write-Host ("MaintainabilityIndex={0}" -f $metric.Attributes["Value"].Value) 
            }
          }       
        }
      }  
    }
  }
}
```

When the script reaches the Switch statement, $nodes.Name evaluates to "Data.dll" in stead of the element name "Metrics", so the script never gets any further along.

I've looked over this script for quite sometime and I can't figure out how to correct that. Any guidance is greatly appreciated! If there is a better way, I'd be happy to hear about that, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$xml = [xml] (Get-Content $MetricsFileName)
foreach ($metric in $xml.CodeMetricsReport.Targets.Target.Modules.Module.Metrics.Metric) {
    switch ($metric.Name) {
        'MaintainabilityIndex' {
            Write-Host "MaintainabilityIndex=$($metric.Value)"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, guys! I'm going to try both and see which one works best for me.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, you can do this with `XPath` as well within PowerShell:

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content foo.xml)
$selectInfo = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -XPath '/CodeMetricsReport/Targets/Target/Modules/Module/Metrics/Metric[@Name="MaintainabilityIndex"]'
"MaintainabilityIndex=$($selectInfo.Node.Value)"
```